# Why location manager is still on when I make it null?

Tags: android, locationmanager, locationlistener

In my app, I am using two location managers for two different activities. First location manager is created when the first activity is created. And then from the first activity I am creating a second activity which is creating a second location manager. In the second activity, I am trying to stop location manager updates using the following code when the back button is pressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  lm.removeUpdates(ll);
  ll = null;
  lm = null;
  finish();
}
```

ll and lm are declared globally in both first and second activity seperatly.
ll and lm are initialized in onCreate of second activity using following code:

```
 lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 ll = new myLocationListener();
 lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, ll);
```

The problem is that if I don't go to the second activity and stop the first activity's location updates, then the GPS sign in my Android goes away. But if I go to the second activity, come back to the first activity using the back button and then stop the first acivity's location updates, then the GPS location sign is still there. I am stopping updates in the first activity using same line of codes:

```
lm.removeUpdates(ll);
ll = null;
lm = null;
```

ll and lm in first activity are initialized when start button is pressed:

```
 public void startClick (View target){
      lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      ll = new myLocationListener();
      lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, ll);
 }
```

Is there any kind of mistake in the code or is there any logical error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show more code please. How are `ll` and `lm` defined? How are they initialized?

Comment: edited my question. please have a look and if there is something confusing then let me know.

Comment: Out of interest, why not stop updates in onPause not onBackPressed. If the user presses the home key in your app it will still receive updates even though it is not in the foreground...

Comment: its a running app. i want user to stop it. it should work even its in background. updates should only be stopped when user clicks stop.

Comment: what do you mean 'll and lm are declared globally'? I still can't see anything that would exhibit this behaviour. Can you add some logging and make sure that you are really disabling the location listener when you think you are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a single instance of the `LocationManager` and store it in your `Application Context`. To do so you need to create a class that extends `Application`. Here's an example:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 
{
   private LocationManager locationManager;

   @Override
   public void onCreate()
   {
     super.onCreate();

     //Initialize here the locationManager or initialize it in one of your
     //Activities. It is your choice.
   }

   //To retrieve the locationManager
   public LocationManager getLocationManger()
   {
      return locationManager;
   }

   //In case you want to initialize the locationManger in one of your Activities
   public void setLocationManager(LocationManager locationMangerIn) 
   {
       locationManager = locationMangerIn;
   }
}
```

Do not forget to add a reference to `MyApplication` in the `android:name` attribute in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Something like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.your_package_name.MyApplication">
```

To access your locationManager instance you call this piece of code:

```
LocationManger lm = ((MyApplication)activitysContext.getApplication()).getLocationManger();
```

To instantiate the locationManager instance inside your Activity you use this:

```
public void startClick (View target){
  LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

  //You can add the listener now or later. Again, your choice.
  ll = new myLocationListener();
  lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, ll);

  ((MyApplication)activitysContext.getApplication()).setLocationManger(lm);
```

}

Hope that helps:)